# Dynamic inserting of SQL extract in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Keep in mind, that i'm rather new to VBA coding

**Problem:**

I have an sql extract in Excel 2013, which works perfectly. However, at the moment the data is hardcoded in relation to where is should be placed. The problem is that whenever a new line is added, that hardcoding doesn't work.

That data is placed below a table, that contains relevant employees, which sums the data enabling me to send it elsewhere in the workbook. However, if a new employee is added the data wont be placed correctly, because of the hardcoding of placement of data. I could create another sheet, but that is not desireable.

What i'm looking for is a piece of code that automatically (dynamically) finds the first empty row and column in the data area and then inserts the data in that place. So the first data should go in the first available row in column A. The next time i extract data it should go in the first available row in Column D and so forth.

To give a picture over Data areas one has headers that in the area A31:CE31, while another is A26:AJ26 - It all depends on the number of columns i extract (and its based on around 12 months, so the same columns for each month)

**Code:**

I've looked around the web for a while, trying to figure out what to do. So far i have the following code - i present also my former hardcoding if formula, so you can get a feel for what is needed. Also keep in mind the code contains much more, but everything works fine, i just need to change this bit.

```
Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long

LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LCol = Cells(LRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

**SQL Extract happening here**

 If Not rs.EOF Then
If Range("A" & LRow + 1).Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & LRow + 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
   ElseIf Range("D10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("G10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("J10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("J10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("M10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("M10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("P10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("P10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("S10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("S10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("V10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("V10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("Y10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("Y10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("AB10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AB10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("AE10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AE10").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ElseIf Range("AH10").Value = "" Then
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("AH10").CopyFromRecordset rs
   End If
rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If
```

I dont know if i have coded it correctly, and also what to do moving forward. The first input of the data works, as it finds the last row in column A correctly - But i can't figure out how to move on from there. Any assistance will be appreciated. I assume it's not that complicated.

**EDIT:**

I want to avoid any form of referencing specific rows or columns. I want it to automatically find the next empty one, and then insert the data - i dont know the next steps for coding that part

Comment: You use your `lRow` value for Column `A` why not do something similar for the rest?

Comment: Because i was unsure if that would move to the next column? I dont want to hardcode column in anyway - i want it to automatically find the next column aswell, if i insert a column in the middle of the data range

Comment: If you're unsure, test it.

Comment: I did try it, and it didn't work as desired. The way i could fix it is to create multiple Lrow lines referring to the specific columns. It's that reference to a specific row or column i'd like to avoid. If i say then add a column in the middle, then i have to change the code aswell - or am i completely off the mark here?

Comment: Have you tried using offset? Ex: To move one cell to the right (from B2 to C2): Range("B2").Offset(0,1).Select

Comment: Little late response. No i havent tried offset yet, but i will as soon as i got time. Something came up at work! Thanks for you answers, all of you - will see if i can get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
Dim c As Range, sht as Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet

Set c = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)

'Locate the first empty "slot"
Do While Len(c.Value) > 0   '<<<<EDIT
    Set c = c.Offset(0, 3)
    'wrap back and one row down if full row
    If c.Column > 43 Then Set c = sht.Cells(c.Row + 1, 1)
Loop

**SQL Extract happening here**

If Not rs.EOF Then 
    c.CopyFromRecordset rs
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

rs.Close '<< still need to close even if no records returned...
```

Comment: The first month (january) runs fine. It puts the info in column A through C, which is perfect. However when i run it once more (february) it doesn't put the data in column D, but in the first empty row below the previous data. I think i didn't describe it properly in the problem